# Imputation package "mi" functions loading error

Tags: r

I have R (3.3.2). I want to impute my dataset missing values by `mi` package. I installed it and run library. But when using `mi.info` function, this error massage appears: could not find function "mi.info". What is problem? Please help me.

Comment: ``mi.info`` is not a function in the package ``mi``

Comment: Thanks, but I saw this function in the "Multiple Imputation with Diagnostics (mi) in R: Opening Windows into the Black Box". In that paper, writers had been referred to that function in the mi package.

Comment: maybe it's deprecated...it was part of that package at least 4 years ago http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/dealing-with-r-type-of-variables-when-doing-multiple-imputation-with-the-mi-pack

Comment: Yeah it appears its been deprecated. Consider contacting the authors of the package or installing an older version of ``mi``.

Answer (score 0):

I installed an older version of r(2.10.1) on a virtual machine (VMware) and installed 0.09-11 `mi` package on it from [cran archive](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.10/). I reached my answer finally and found collinearity between my variables by `mi.info`function.